# EazyBI - how to display all labels assigned to the issue

Tags: jira, mdx

I have label imported as dimension, but would like to display as a column all the labels set for the issues. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be following:

```
Generate(
  Filter(Descendants([Label].CurrentMember,[Label].[Label]),
    [Measures].[Issues created]>0
  ),
  [Label].CurrenthierarchyMember.Name,
  ","
)
```